# Twilio Client - Sometimes no receiving disconnect from the caller

Tags: twilio

We're using twilio client (1.4) to place/receive calls and we have noticed that sometimes when the caller hangs up the call, twilio client doesn't receive the disconnect signaling and therefore, it keeps like it has a ongoing call.

Could we somehow avoid or minimize this behavior?

Regards,
Carlos

Comment: If you are finding issues like this it would be better to report them to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). If you could include call SIDs from times that this happened, that would be even more useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check call status issue in twilio website www.twilio.com with your credentitals. Go to calllogs and find the particular call(with SID- this Sid you can get it from twilio.device.incoming method ) and check the call status http response.(Most probably your statuscallback has some issue)